# Посчитать все значения на странице

Tags: jquery

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Название блюда</th>
      <th id="summ">5000</th>
   </tr>
</table>

<table>
   <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Название блюда</th>
      <th id="summ">13000</th>
   </tr>
</table>
```

На странице есть несколько таблиц, точное количество не известно,
как на jquery посчитать и вывести сумму всех значений с id="summ"

Comment: Для начала прекратите уже эту порочную практику добавлять много элементов с одним и тем же id. Идентификатор потому так и зовётся, что каждый на странице должен быть один. Нужны повторы - используйте классы или атрибут data-, например, data-id="summ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнём с того, что [атрибут `id`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/id) должен быть уникальным.

По этому мы заменим атрибут `id` на `class` и посчитаем:

```js
let sum = 0; // Создадим начальную переменную.

$('.summ').each(function(){ // Пройдёмся по всем элементам..
  let thisSum = $(this).text(); // Получим содержимое элемента
  if($.isNumeric(thisSum)) { // если это число, то идём дальше.
    thisSum = parseInt(thisSum); // преобразуем значение в число.
    sum += thisSum; // прибавляем к переменной sum
  }
});

console.info(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
   <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Название блюда</th>
      <th class="summ">5000</th>
   </tr>
</table>

<table>
   <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Название блюда</th>
      <th class="summ">13000</th>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/jog960uw/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "th#summ" ).each(function() {
    counter+=Number($( this ).text());
    });
  alert(counter);
});
```

Note: The ID values should be unique, use class insted.